# Add a border to the slices of a pieChart in dc.js + labelColors

Tags: d3.js, pie-chart, dc.js

I need to add a border to my slices as I have some adjacent ones which use the same color (my `colorAccessor` is a positive/negative->green/red).

As a bonus I would like to be able to set the label colors as well.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Don't think that there's an option for that in dc.js, so you would have to do it yourself.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I found what I was looking for after hardcore googling in the depth of the dc.js github. I thought this might be useful to someone else.

You need to do that directly in the `svg` object using the `css` styling.

```
#id-of-your-chart path{
    stroke: white;
    stroke-width: 2;
}
```